# If blue is coded as 118 then colour is coded as?

Tags: word, pattern

I couldn't find the exact solution for the following "Coding - Decoding" problem that I found in some exam paper. The question is as follows:

> If blue is coded as 118 then colour is coded as?

Comment: ...then colour is coded as: number. Easy ;D

Comment: @Avigrail ... or as emergency service name :D (red is firefighters)

Comment: When you spend time calculating things and you just notice that they are no math tag D:

Comment: I think @Avigrail has got it and it's a crappy question :-)

Comment: The question is very vague but I attempted to answer it as best as possible.

Answer (score 3):

Colour is coded as

> Number

Or maybe

> Integer

Or possibly even

> Whole Number

Why:

> Colour is a generalized version of a specific colour, for example blue. So if blue is to 118, then we must generalize 118. Giving us "Number", "Integer", or "Whole Number"